# Oracle SQL query to get data from a csv file into the IN condition

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a requirement to get data from one of header in a comma separated CSV file into a oracle SQL query and generate a report.

**Input CSV File :**

```
USERNAME,column2,Column3
CC1234,adsfasdf,AB34568
CC1864,etwetwee,AB78966
CC7686,knblfklf,AB90867
```

**SQL query**

```sql
select login,firstname,lastname from table where login in (header2 values from csv file);
```

**Output :**

```
login,firstname,lastname
```

Can we achieve this using Oracle SQL ? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To read csv data into SQL Query, you can use below methods:

1. Load CSV file into table(you can use sql loader) and use that table in SQL
2. Use external table - For External table you should have access for create Directory
3. Use UTL_File

So with above method, you can join csv data into joins as any other table.